# Strange color in UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiactionsheet

Today I added one UIActionSheet to my project and it displayed very strangely:

[image]

As you can see, the action sheet displays only text - no buttons - and the background is completely black. I just want to have default style of UIActionSheet on my app.

I'm using Storyboards and here is the code to present the action sheet:

```
UIActionSheet *_actionSheet = [[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:LocStr(@"Cell_TellFriend_Key") delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:LocStr(@"Cancel_Key") destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:LocStr(@"EmailShare_Key"),LocStr(@"FacebookShare_Key"),LocStr(@"TwitterShare_Key"),nil] autorelease];

_actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[_actionSheet showFromTabBar:appDelegate.tabbarCtrl.tabBar];
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: post some code u used to show the `UIActionSheet`

Comment: Put the code in your question so people can read it.

Comment: OK, i put it already.

Comment: Post some code to check.

Comment: There must be some other problem as your code is completely fine. I used it (without `LocStr` ofcourse) and it looks good,

Answer (score 1):

```
_actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
```

Comment: Yep, someone added extention to UIActionSheet and I haven't recognized it. I commented out these methods and it just works.